# Why can't functions have delays?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog

Verilog and VHDL both prohibit delays in functions. Also, tasks/procedures cannot have a return value. This means code like this:

```
if (my_function(arg) > 0) begin (...) end
```

must be replaced by

```
int r;
my_task(arg, r);
if (r > 0) begin (...) end
```

if delays are needed. Why this limitation? It appears that even SystemVerilog class member functions have it, which makes little sense to me.

For synthesis delays can obviously not be supported, but having the synthesis tool produce an error when encountering a delay would be perfectly acceptable, like it does for delays in `always`/`process` blocks.

Comment: This goes back to the basic language design principle that expressions should be stateless and have no side-effects. Functions being abstractions over expressions.

Comment: Impure functions can have side-effects. In the first code example above, my_function() can modify a module-level signal. In SystemVerilog you can even spawn a background thread with a function, which is a pretty clear violation of this principle as far as I can tell.

Comment: For VHDL IEEE Std 1076-2008  9.3.4 Function calls, 10.2 Wait statement para 9 "It is an error if a wait statement appears in a function subprogram or in a procedure that has a parent that is a function subprogram"). A function call is an expression, "... a formula that defines the computation of a value" (9.1) and a function may supply a value in a declaration (6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 9.2, 4.5.2, 16.2),  while a "...wait statement causes the suspension of a process statement ..." (10.2). Expressions aren't found solely in statements.

Comment: Yes, I remember this; this must have been fun to implement for the VHDL simulator vendors. You can even have a function calling a procedure calling another procedure, and if the second procedure contains a wait statement the simulator is supposed to throw an error at compile time. In Verilog it is not allowed to call a task from a function at all, which sounds a lot easier to implement.

Comment: You have to have the ability to search back up the 'as elaborated' tree to identify process drivers for signals anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The rules for tasks and functions are the same regardless of whether they are a class method or not. A function must never block, and call to a function, whether it returns a value or not (void) forms a guarantee that it does will block.

This rule from Verilog was required because functions were part of expressions and there could never be a delay in the middle of an expression. Now it used to show intent, and other rules in SystemVerilog take advantage of this non-blocking intent. (i.e. DPI).

Comment: Delays in the middle of an expression does sound like something to avoid. On the other hand, the behavior would be unambiguous with existing rules, as far as I can tell. (E.g., execute from left to right and stop when the result is known.) I would argue that in many cases allowing delays in functions or return values in tasks would provide significantly more readable code.